# Where is struct vop_vector declared?

Tags: c, header-files, freebsd, vfs

I'm trying to understand the VFS of FreeBSD 10.3. One of its central structures is the `struct vop_vector` which contains function pointers to the implementations of the abstract file system operations.

I expected it to be declared in `/usr/include/sys/vnode.h` but it wasn't there. After 10 minutes of searching I haven't found the place where this structure is declared. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWK script `/sys/tools/vnode_if.awk` generates the declaration with the option `-q`:

```
/sys/tools/vnode_if.awk /sys/kern/vnode_if.src -q
```

Comment: Any specific reason as to why such awk scripts (and perhaps other mechanisms used in conjunction with `.src` files) are being used to generate these (and perhaps other structures/entities) at run-time instead of having them declared outright?

Comment: @HighOnMeat I have not the slightest clue. One possibility is that the same script also generates templates for new file systems.